# How to create an array from user selected objects in IONIC 3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to differentiate the selected array I get from user but i am unable to separate it . It just come together.

Like i am trying to get it like below image

[image]

but this is what i am getting shown in below image

[image]

this is how Im doing in my .ts file

```
sub_item: any = [{
subcat_id: "",
value: "",
qty: ""
}];

constructor(...){
..
}

submitbtn(){
this.sub_item.push({
      subcat_id: this.sub_id,
      qty: this.quantity,
      value: this.addonId + "|" + this.addOnPrice + "|" + this.selectedAddOn
    });
}
```

Any help is heartily appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like so:

```
 sub_item: any = [{
 subcat_id: "",
 value: "",
 qty: ""
}];


this.sub_item[0].subcat_id = this.sub_id;
this.sub_item[0].qty = this.quantity;
this.sub_item[0].value = this.addOnPrice + "|" + this.selectedAddOn;
```

To add another item, you can do like so:

```
sub_item.push({
   subcat_id: 1,
   qty: 3,
   value: '101|102|Paneer'
})
```

Comment: Showing the same result as before :(